# Java regex - alphanumeric, at most one hyphen, period or underscore, seven characters long

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to the regex tool in Java, and despite their great potential I'm having a hard time accomplishing this task. I want to write a regex to validate an input string which respects the following syntax:

1. any combination of lowercase letters and digits
2. only one underscore, one dash or one period (no other special characters)
3. minimum length of 5

I came up with the following solution:

([/./-_]{0,1}[a-z0-9]){5,}

but in some cases it still doesn't work, for example it does not match a string where one of the special characters allowed is in the middle (such as he-llo). Where did I go wrong? Is there any other pattern better than this for my purpose?

Comment: Generally it helps to show the code you tested with, just in case it's a coding error.  Also, some things cannot use regex, and must be parsed.  Most folks prefer a parser as the result is cleaner to maintain.

Comment: You will need lookaheads.

Comment: Where underscore, dash or period can be placed (at the beginning, in the middle, at the end)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one? You use look ahead to verify there are at least 5 characters.

```
^(?=.{5})[a-z0-9]*([-_.][a-z0-9]*)?$
```

Comment: It is almost right. You need to wrap `[-_.][a-z0-9]*` with an optional group. Also, `(?=.{5,})` can be replaced with `(?=.{5})`, it is enough.

Comment: OK. Did not see the optional requirement. Thanks.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it with regex. Because of the fact that things can appear in any order, it's easier without:

```
if (str.length() < 5) {
  return false;
}
int specialCharacterCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
  char c = str.charAt(i);
  if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
    // A lowercase letter.
  } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    // A number.
  } else if ("_.-".indexOf(c) >= 0) {
    // An allowed special character.
    ++specialCharacterCount;
  } else {
    // Some other character - immediately invalid.
    return false;
  }
}
// Return true if there is at most one of _, . and -.
return specialCharacterCount <= 1;
```

Comment: Far less lines of code are needed with a regular expression.

Comment: @Jan <shrug> I'll take something like this which I can debug easily any day of the week.

Comment: The old joke is that someone who solves a problem with regex then has two problems.  Maintainable code is more of an issue than "lines of code."  Complexity (and readability) matters; regex has neither.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it all in one regex:

```
^                        # start string
(?=[^-_.]*[-_.][^-_.]*$) # lookahead fulfilling condition 2
([-_.\w]{5,})            # all allowed characters at least 5
$                        # end of string
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gOEkEK/1) and note that you'll need double backslashes in `Java`, so that your expression becomes:

```
^(?=[^-_.]*[-_.][^-_.]*$)([-_.\\w]{5,})$
```